# Is it possible to solve the equation $\nabla_x F(x) = G(x)$ with respect to x, where F is a known scalar field and G is a known vector field?

Tags: numerical-methods

Is there a numerical method to solve this equation, considering that we cannot write out the specific expressions for F or G, but can numerically compute the gradient or function value information at a certain point x? Can anyone provide some suggestions? In regard to my specific problem, $F(x) = \frac{||f(x)||^2_2}{2}$. f(x) is a known function from $R^n$ to $R^n$. $G(x)=\frac{a}{x}+b$.

$a$ and $b$ are constant vectors, and  the division operation is element-wise division.

I can also compute the function value of $f^{-1}(x)$， I'm not sure if this would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by “solve”? If $F$ and $G$ are both known, what is there to solve?

Comment: I want to find a solution for some x that makes this equation equal.

Comment: This equation is not valid for any arbitrary x; I want to find the numerical solution for x that makes the equation hold true. "Known" means that the function value and derivative can be calculated at a specific point, but the explicit expression is unknown.

Comment: Ah, your differential equations tags led me to believe you were solving for a function. To solve any kind of nonlinear equation you can use a root-finding algorithm like Newton’s method.